# What is more efficient on the CPU? Is the difference worth it?

Tags: java

I was wondering if creating repetitive code to avoid a variable is more efficient on the CPU, and if it is, is it worth repeating code like the example below?

I currently have the following:

```
c.set("arenas."+name+".team"+team+".world", loc.getWorld().getName());
c.set("arenas."+name+".team"+team+".x", loc.getX());
c.set("arenas."+name+".team"+team+".y", loc.getY());
c.set("arenas."+name+".team"+team+".z", loc.getZ());
c.set("arenas."+name+".team"+team+".pitch", loc.getPitch());
c.set("arenas."+name+".team"+team+".yaw", loc.getYaw());3
```

Would the following be faster on the CPU. It does the same thing as the code above:

```
if(team == 1) {
    c.set("arenas."+name+".team1.world", loc.getWorld().getName());
    c.set("arenas."+name+".team1.x", loc.getX());
    c.set("arenas."+name+".team1.y", loc.getY());
    c.set("arenas."+name+".team1.z", loc.getZ());
    c.set("arenas."+name+".team1.pitch", loc.getPitch());
    c.set("arenas."+name+".team1.yaw", loc.getYaw());
}else {
    c.set("arenas."+name+".team2.world", loc.getWorld().getName());
    c.set("arenas."+name+".team2.x", loc.getX());
    c.set("arenas."+name+".team2.y", loc.getY());
    c.set("arenas."+name+".team2.z", loc.getZ());
    c.set("arenas."+name+".team2.pitch", loc.getPitch());
    c.set("arenas."+name+".team2.yaw", loc.getYaw());
}
```

In the second example, would the if-else statement be faster than joining six strings together in the first example?

I am aware that this will take more disk space, but will it save processing power? Is it worth it?

EDIT: I performed a test with 100,000,000 trials on each. It took 11.112 seconds for example 1 and 9.479 seconds for example 2. Example 2 was 1.633 seconds faster. Is it worth it? If CPU and disk space was important, would I use example 1?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just try each in a loop to see which runs faster?

Comment: The `if` statement probably is faster than string concatenation, but it's not worth it. Plus, if optimizing this code actually did matter for some reason, this isn't how you'd go about it. You'd probably write some kind of caching mechanism, or avoid using strings altogether.

Comment: @DonBranson Just did a test, and posted it in an edit.

Comment: @Radiodef You were right, and that would be a good idea. It is no big deal with what I am working with, but I was curious to know.

Comment: If you want efficiency, you should create a domain model using classes. Working on untyped data in maps like you do is sometimes acceptable in scripting languages, but it makes your code hard to maintain and perform worse. You only expect to see these kind of data structures at the boundaries of your application when saving/loading data and communicating with other applications, when IO overhead is typically much higher than such minor performance differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefer readability over micro optimization (in fact, your current approach is likely to be more efficient than your proposed alternative because branching is comparatively expensive - but don't micro optimize). I would extract a method to build the key (again, maximize readability). Like,

```
private static String buildKey(String name, int team, String key) {
    return String.format("arenas.%s.team%d.%s", name, team, key);
}
```

Then you can invoke it like,

```
c.set(buildKey(name, team, "world"), loc.getWorld().getName());
c.set(buildKey(name, team, "x"), loc.getX());
c.set(buildKey(name, team, "y"), loc.getY());
c.set(buildKey(name, team, "z"), loc.getZ());
c.set(buildKey(name, team, "pitch"), loc.getPitch());
c.set(buildKey(name, team, "yaw"), loc.getYaw());
```